# problem with loops and fetchcolum in php?

Tags: php, pdo, logic

I got an $arrayDirectoy variable which contains just 2 values, then I tried to pass that variable to a query in a for loop to retrieve the ids of each one, but It just echo me one id, and there are two ids, I dont know how to fix that, It just print me 1 id.

Example $arrayDirectory[] = {user1, user2};

it must echo 1 2 but just print me 1

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arrayDirectory;$i++){ 
    $res[$i] = $obj->obtainID($arrayDirectory[$i]);

    echo $res[$i];

}
```

this is my obtainID method

```
public function obtainID($user){

        $conexion = $this->objConexion->configuracion();
        $query = "CALL sp_xxx('$user')";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: I assume it depends on what your procedure `sp_xx()` does.

Comment: my store procedure is ok I think the error Its in the for loop It just print 1 value and it must be two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
foreach($arrayDirectory as $a)
{
 echo $obj->obtainID($a);
}
```

if this still do the same as ur for loop the problem will be something else

Comment: I already try in that way but It is the same, It just print 1, thanks

Comment: check if your array contains two elements !!! 
print_r($arrayDirectory); 
show me the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => ara [1] => val ) 1

Comment: dear u loop run fine the problem in $obj->obtainID($a); 
i returns nothing for the second index right ??

Comment: yes but in navicat it works, I still dont know why it does not return nothing in the loop